# How to keep the active link in a non-exact route with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an application with Vue and VueRouter, in my root component I have a tab panel, each tab is a router-link, when I click on each routerlink it takes me to the specific route, until then everything is fine, for example the route `misitio.com/shop/` activate the link for this route

the problem is when within that route there is another component that leads to `mysitio.com/shop/categories`, I would like to leave the link of the route `mysite.com/shop` active but it is not like that.

Example Code

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs nav-justified default-color-dark" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'shop'}" exact
                        class="nav-link  text-white" 
                        data-toggle="tab"
                        role="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-table"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; SHOP
                    </router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'other'}"  exact
                    class="nav-link  text-white" 
                        data-toggle="tab"
                        role="tab" >
                        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; OTHER
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content card">
                <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </transition>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The urls of my tabs are

1. midominio.com/shop/
2. midominio.com/shop/categories/

if I do not use exact, when I select the second option the first one also marks me

How can I achieve this behavior? I thought of a regular expression maybe to activate the link

Comment: isn't because you are using the `exact` prop ?

Comment: I had thought about it but, if I do not use exact, it always marks the first option of my tab since there are two links
1. mydomain.com/shop/
2. mydomain.com/shop/categories/

Comment: not a good solution, but it could be solve by controlling the active class like `v-bind:active-class="$route.path !== '/shop/categories/' ? '(your active class)' : ''`

Comment: or `v-bind:exact="$route.path === '/shop/categories/'"`

Comment: @JacobGoh You might be encouraged to add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best solutions, but these are the ways that your problem could be solved:

1. controlling the active class like `v-bind:active-class="$route.path
   !== '/shop/categories/' ? '(your active class)' : ''`
2. control the `exact` prop like `v-bind:exact="$route.path ===
   '/shop/categories/'"`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply with [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

The interesting part in the doc is [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-named-routes) when they tell how to use a default child route.

```js
const routes = [
// ...
    {
        path: '/shop',
        children: [
            {
                path: '', // <- Default route
                name: 'shop',
                component: Shop,
            },
            {
                path: 'categories',
                name: 'categories',
                component: Categories,
            },
        ],
    },
// ...
]
```

This will match the `shop` route on `/shop` (since the child route with the path `''` is matched by default) and the `categories` on `/shop/categories`

Then `/shop/categories` will be matched "non exact" but at least with the (default) `router-link-active` css class

You can even have a different root path (not `/shop`) in your children routes as soon as you use a leading `/`